# how to calculate the special integral related to Chebyshev polynomials?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind, $V_n(x)$, can be defined as
$$V_n(x)=\frac{\sin(n+1)\theta}{\sin\theta}, \hspace{5mm} x=2\cos\theta,$$
or through the recurrence relation
$$V_{n+1}=xV_n-V_{n-1}, \, V_0=1, \, V_1=x.$$
First few low-order Chebyshev polynomials of the second
kind are as follows:
$$V_0=1, \, V_1=x, \, V_2=x^2-1, \, V_3=x^3-2x,$$
$$V_4=x^4-3x^2+1, \, V_5=x^5-4x^3+3x.$$

I want to know how to calculate the following integral relate to Chebyshev polynomials:
$$\int_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\right)^m dx$$
where $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

It is easy to see the following result:

For an even number $n  \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and and odd number $m \in \mathbb{N}$, we have

$$ \int_0^\pi \left(\frac {\sin nx}{\sin x}\right)^{m} dx=0.$$

I prefer to know the other two cases beside the above special case.   Thank you.

Comment: For $m<0$ and $|n|\ne 0$ the integral it's not defined. And $m=0$ is a trivial case. Your question makes only sense for $m\ge 0$ .

Comment: You should give a look at the Dirichlet kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Comments.*

*Trivial cases:* For $n=0, m>0$ the result is $0$ . For $m=0$ or $n=1$ the result is $\pi$ . For $n<0, m>0$ it's the result for $n>0, m>0$ multiplicated with $(-1)^m$ . For $m<0, |n|>1$ the integral doesn't work.

Let $\,n,m\in\mathbb{N}\,$ , $\,k\in\mathbb{N}_0\,$ and $\,a_{m,k}\in\mathbb{Q}^+\,$ . Then we set

> $$\int\limits_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}\right)^m dx = \pi n^{\frac{1+(-1)^m}{2}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{ \lfloor \frac{m-1}{2}\rfloor } a_{m,k} n^{2k} $$

where $\,a_{m,k}\,$ can be evaluated with a linear equation system,

if one knows $\enspace\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}\right)^m dx\enspace$ for $\enspace\displaystyle n\in\{1,2,…,{ \lfloor \frac{m+1}{2}\rfloor }\}\enspace$ .

*Examples:*

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}\right)^1 dx = \pi\enspace$ for odd $\,n\,$ otherwise $\,0\,$

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}\right)^2 dx = \pi n$

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}\right)^3 dx =\frac{\pi}{4}(1+3n^2)\enspace$ for odd $\,n\,$ otherwise $\,0\,$

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}\right)^4 dx = \frac{\pi n}{3}(1+2n^2)$

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}\right)^5 dx =\frac{\pi}{192}(27+50n^2+115n^4)\enspace$ for odd $\,n\,$ otherwise $\,0\,$

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}\right)^6 dx = \frac{\pi n}{20}(4+5n^2+11n^4)$

*Hint:*

For a proof and to get the coefficients it makes sense to use

> $$\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{ix(2k+1-n)}$$

which makes it necessary to use *multinomials*.

$\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}$ is real therefore the imaginary parts of $\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{ix(2k+1-n)}\right)^m$ can be ignored.

*Links:*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_Theorem

(If the last link doesn’t work please use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series instead, look for “Generalization to multinomials” .)

Comment: Thank you. Great work!  Can you give the proof for the formula:$$\int\limits_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}\right)^m dx = \pi n^{\frac{1+(-1)^m}{2}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{ \lfloor \frac{m-1}{2}\rfloor } a_{m,k} n^{2k} $$

Comment: I conjecured also that the result is a polynomial $P(n)$ of order $m-1$.  I know that it is true when $m=1,2,3,4$. But NO proof yet for $m\geq 5.$

Comment: @Jacob.Z.Lee : I think a good start will be to use $~\displaystyle\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{ix(2k+1-n)}~$ .

Comment: good. then use residue theorem in complex theory.

Comment: @Jacob.Z.Lee : Not really. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_Theorem , that's enough to get a general formula. No complex theory is necessary, only to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula .

Comment: $\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}=2[\cos(2k-1)x+\cos(2k-3)x+\cdots+\cos x]$ if $n=2k$;$\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}=2[\cos(2k )x+\cos(2k-2)x+\cdots+\cos 2x]+1$ if $n=2k+1$;\\ Then the integral  will be reduced to a complicated combinatoric problem.

Comment: @Jacob.Z.Lee : Please use $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{ix(2k+1-n)}\enspace$ otherwise it becomes too complicate. E.g. $~\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\pi \left(\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin x}\right)^4 dx = \int\limits_0^\pi (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^4 dx = ...\enspace$ . (multinomials)

Comment: $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^4=\left( {e}^{{\it ix}} \right) ^{4}+4\, \left( {e}^{{\it ix}} \right) 
^{2}+6+4\, \left( {e}^{{\it ix}} \right) ^{-2}+ \left( {e}^{{\it ix}}
 \right) ^{-4}$, how to calculate its integral from 0 to $\pi$ without complex theory?

Comment: @Jacob.Z.Lee : $\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\pi (e^{ix})^n dx = \int\limits_0^{\pi} e^{inx} dx = \frac{e^{inx}}{in}|_0^{\pi} = \frac{(-1)^n-1}{in}$ --- The example above: All the imaginary parts disappear (because the integral is real) and $6$ is left which means the result is $6\pi$ .

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: When $n$ is a big number, the problem is reduced to the determination of  the  middle coefficient of the multinomial expansion.